# JavaFX program does not run when VM Options set to one directory, but runs fine when set to another directory with the same files

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

I have a project in IntelliJ (Java 11) containing two modules. One is a simple java module and the other is a JavaFX program. These are both empty as I am setting up the project structure for use on Git and am trying to get rid of any absolute file paths.

At the root of the project is a lib folder that contains all of the JARs for JavaFX (plus some others for JUnit). These were copied directly from the folder I originally extracted JavaFX to (and which I still use fine when building non-Git JavaFX projects) when I first used the framework.

I have these JARs added as dependencies in the project. Any code using them shows with no errors in the IDE. I know that to get the JavaFX project to run I must add `--module-path <path to JavaFX libs> --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml` to the VM options in my run configuration. This is where the problem is.

When I use the path to the original extraction location of JavaFX I was talking about earlier, everything works fine (i.e. the window of the program opens): `--module-path C:/Tools/JavaFX/lib/ --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml`.

However, when I use the path to the lib folder in my project that contains the same files (plus JUnit ones), it does not work (I get runtime errors and the program does not display its window): `--module-path C:/Users/Henry/Documents/IntelliJ/LAA_Rotas_4/lib/ --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml`

Below is the runtime output:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11\bin\java.exe" --module-path C:/Users/Henry/Documents/IntelliJ/LAA_Rotas_4/lib/ --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.2.4\lib\idea_rt.jar=57474:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.2.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\Henry\Documents\IntelliJ\LAA_Rotas_4\out\production\Demo;C:\Users\Henry\Documents\IntelliJ\LAA_Rotas_4\lib\apiguardian-api-1.0.0.jar;C:\Users\Henry\Documents\IntelliJ\LAA_Rotas_4\lib\javafx-swt.jar;C:\Users\Henry\Documents\IntelliJ\LAA_Rotas_4\lib\javafx.base.jar;C:\Users\Henry\Documents\IntelliJ\LAA_Rotas_4\lib\javafx.controls.jar;C:\Users\Henry\Documents\IntelliJ\LAA_Rotas_4\lib\javafx.fxml.jar;C:\Users\Henry\Documents\IntelliJ\LAA_Rotas_4\lib\javafx.graphics.jar;C:\Users\Henry\Documents\IntelliJ\LAA_Rotas_4\lib\javafx.media.jar;C:\Users\Henry\Documents\IntelliJ\LAA_Rotas_4\lib\javafx.swing.jar;C:\Users\Henry\Documents\IntelliJ\LAA_Rotas_4\lib\javafx.web.jar;C:\Users\Henry\Documents\IntelliJ\LAA_Rotas_4\lib\junit-jupiter-api-5.3.1.jar;C:\Users\Henry\Documents\IntelliJ\LAA_Rotas_4\lib\junit-platform-commons-1.3.1.jar;C:\Users\Henry\Documents\IntelliJ\LAA_Rotas_4\lib\opentest4j-1.1.1.jar net.atos.laa_rotas.demo.Main
Graphics Device initialization failed for :  d3d, sw
Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer.getInstance(QuantumRenderer.java:280)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.init(QuantumToolkit.java:222)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:260)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:267)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:158)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:658)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:409)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:94)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:124)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No toolkit found
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:272)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:267)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:158)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:658)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:409)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    ... 5 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Internally, in the workspace.xml file for IntelliJ, those VM options get converted to `--module-path $PROJECT_DIR$/lib/ --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml`. However, even if I directly set that path to `C:/Users/Henry/Documents/IntelliJ/LAA_Rotas_4/lib/` in the workspace.xml file and reload and run the project, nothing changes.

Does anyone know why this is happening and what can be done to fix it?

Comment: JavaFX SDK for Windows contains the jars in the `lib` folder but also the native dll libraries in the `bin` folder, that's why the original path works for you.

Comment: @JoséPereda Wow, thank you! What's the recommended way for including JavaFX in my project then? Aren't the jars made so programs can be cross-platform? Requiring dlls would tie it to Windows only. Do I need to download a different, cross platform version that just uses jars?

Comment: There is no version that "just uses jars", each platform has some native libraries. Have a look at the starting [guide](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/) and to the different related [samples](https://github.com/openjfx/samples), and find the scenario that adjust to your case.

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced same problem but i found the fix for this you just need to add this in Your intelliJ VM Options,

**Right Click on your Main class and then click on Modify Run Configuration and after that add this following lines in Your VMoptions and make sure to replace the Directory**

```
    --module-path
"C:\Users\your-directory\javafx-sdk-16\lib"
--add-modules
"javafx.controls,javafx.fxml"
```

and make sure you have all the files and directory of javafx sdk in same Directory where **lib** folder is located

**bin**
**legal**
**lib**